# How careful should we be about citing other answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

To quote the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> **Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by *you* as part of the
>   [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) network of Q&A sites.
>   With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed
>   answers to every question about programming.

Ideally, we should be able to build upon the efforts of others in creating our answers to avoid duplicating effort and to perpetuate useful information. Yet I manage to be surprised when users such as [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333270/3920237) come along and correct highly upvoted, year old answers.

This casts doubt on the validity of arbitrary answers which look correct, and may have been cited by other answers, but don't get corrected until later. Yes, we're encouraged to post our own answers as well as downvoting incorrect answers, but the incorrect information may have already done its damage and exist in different questions or answers... many people may not even see Wakely's answer.

So I repeat my question, how careful do we need to be about citing other answers?

Comment: What does citing have to do with the decision of edit vs. post own answer?

Comment: So your question is "How do we make certain that every single answer is absolutely perfect and never needs to be edited in the future before we cite it elsewhere?"

Answer (score 2):

*Caveat emptor* always applies, everywhere, in all of life.

Even if you're not directly *citing* answers, you may have been "indoctrinated" into a wrong belief by reading incorrect information elsewhere, and you may be disseminating your wrong beliefs through your own original answers. Everyone does this all their life in every aspect of human existence.

The important part is that information *can* change, and that we need to embrace this change when it happens. If we do that, we're slowly but surely advancing the state of the art and our own knowledge.

So if you are disseminating information in any form, you need to take care according to how verified the information is. If you're just citing someone else without having verified the information yourself or being unable to ultimately verify the information, simply say so. *"I haven't verified this, but X points in the direction of..."*

You can only sell information as the absolute truth when you're personally convinced of it. When you're not and you're mostly just taking someone's word for it, never present that information as perfect. Everything comes with a degree of certainty attached, just state it as it is.